# Photoshop - Camera Raw filter distorts color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter, raw-format

I am really new to PS, I am trying to improve myself from books and by watching tutorials. I am using CC 2017 and every time I try to use a Camera raw filter, my pictures are looking strange in Camera raw.

This one is the original:

[[image: original]]
Click for full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki7Gl.jpg)

And thats how it looks like in Camera Raw:

[[image: camera raw]]
Click for full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSaJh.jpg)

What am I doing wrong? Is it some misconfiguration with Camera Raw, or my pictures are in bad format, or I am missing something?

What can cause this?

Comment: This is probably a CMYK JPG file, which is sometimes an issue with JPG filters. Disable camera raw for JPG (PS preferences (probably under the edit menu > camera raw preferences), open it, and check the title bar or look at the the image mode. While JFIF files (the file format for jpg compression) supports any number of color channels, most software expects 3-channel RGB

Comment: Hey Yorik, can you post that as an answer, so it's searchable, votable and acceptable. Comments are really just for commenting on a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried applying Camera RAW as a filter to that JPEG in Photoshop CC 2017, but I can't replicate the problem.

To make sure we are all singing from the same hymn sheet, download the original image here: http://orig06.deviantart.net/687c/f/2012/044/c/9/background_stock372_by_sophiefzy-d4pktn5.jpg

Open the JPEG in Photoshop, click `Filter` > `Convert for Smart Filters`, then `Filter` > `Camera RAW filter`.

If that doesn't work, then there is something wrong. Here are some steps you might want to try to find the problem:

1. First thing I would try is quit Photoshop, and restart your computer. It could just be a glitch.
2. If that doesn't work, make sure you've installed the most recent version of Photoshop CC 2017, and that the latest Camera RAW CC is installed - it should show as "Up to date" in your Creative Cloud app.
3. If that doesn't work, make sure you graphics card driver is up to date with the most recent driver.
4. If that doesn't fix it, then restart Photoshop but hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> as you double click the program icon to launch the program. This will reset Photoshop's preferences to default.
5. If that doesn't work, time to call Adobe customer support.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, the driver update did the trick!